# how do you calculate internet speed using pings?

Tags: networking, ping, bandwidth, speedtest

When I try to check speed on SpeedTest.net, it says selecting best server based on pings. Does it calculate the speed using the ping request and reply packets if so how?

Comment: No, it doesn't calculate speed using the ping request from what I can tell. When you see that it's simply selecting the closest server that it can check the download speed from, so that the end return is accurate.

Answer (score 1):

From the speedtest.net [support page](https://support.speedtest.net/hc/en-us/articles/203845290-What-is-ping-download-speed-and-upload-speed-),

> The ping is the reaction time of your connection–how fast you get a
>   response after you've sent out a request. A fast ping means a more
>   responsive connection, especially in applications where timing is
>   everything (like video games). Ping is measured in milliseconds (ms).

There are other frequently asked questions with answer in their support section, including [How does Speedtest.net know where I am?](https://support.speedtest.net/hc/en-us/articles/203845670-How-does-Speedtest-net-know-where-I-am-). However, these are very broad descriptions. More on `ping` can be found by reading about the [utility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_(networking_utility)), as well as the [ICMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol).

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question. It explains what ping is but it doesn't explain that ping isn't used to calculate speed.